# numberformatexception and edittext in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, numberformatexception

Following code gives me numberformatexception. can you please tell me where to put exepcions or what to do about following lines? logcat tells that there is a problem on commented line

```
public void zaplatiti(){
   EditText zbrojka = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
   Float[] strings = new Float[allTexts.size()];
   Float zbroj=(float) 0;
   for(int i=0; i < allTexts.size(); i++){
       strings[i] = Float.valueOf(allTexts.get(i).getText().toString());////problem


   }
   for (int k=0;k<strings.length;k++){
       zbroj =zbroj+ strings[k];}

   }
   zbrojka.setText(String.valueOf(zbroj)+"KN");
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i < allTexts.size(); i++){
    try {
        strings[i] = Float.valueOf(allTexts.get(i).getText().toString());////problem
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // Code to execute if the entered value is not a number
    }
}
```

This is also possible to avoid by only allowing your EditTexts to have numerical values. That will force the user to only enter a numerical value in the first place, then you don't have to catch the exception. But then you should check if the entered text is empty first.

EDIT:

For doing this you must make an `if` statement, but the correct comparison beetween String values is:

```
if ( mEditText.getText().toString().equals("String to compare with")){ ... }
```

the "numerical mode" of an `editText` could be set up in the XML file as:

```
android:inputType = "number"
```

Other valid numerical modes are `numberSigned` and `numberDecimal`.

So after changing the input type your code could look like:

```
for(int i=0; i < allTexts.size(); i++){
    if (!allTexts.get(i).getText().toString().equals("")) {
        strings[i] = Float.valueOf(allTexts.get(i).getText().toString());////problem
    }
    else {
        // Code to execute if there is no entered value
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i do that? i know that i have to check them if they are empty, but how? i tried with if statement but it didnit work...

Comment: @ZliSin please look at the edits and show us how you tried if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the allTexts Array type?

Comment: arrays are: List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();
  List<TextView> allTexts = new ArrayList<TextView>();

Comment: idea is that i have to input in dynamically set edittext numbers, in another it multiplies it with constant and than it shows it in one edittext view. problem start when there are more than one open, and he tries to take them all and it block it because of value "".

Comment: @ZliSin are you sure that you should use `allTexts.get(i)...`, shouldn't you use `allEds.get(i)...`?